# How to position DIV without destroying the vertical alignment?

Tags: css, alignment

I've been struggling with this for hours and cannot find the solution. I've made a simple layout to display two pairs of gauge+thermometer visualizations to show the temperatures uploaded by ESP8266. The basic layout is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>The title</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container_main">
    <div id="heading"><h1>The title</h1></div>
    <div class="graph">
      <div id="container">
        <div id="inner">
          <div id="gauge_div"></div>
          <div class="below_gauge">Text #1</div>
          <div class="below_gauge2">Here I would like to display some text but would not like the left square to be misaligned with the right one.</div>
        </div>
        <div id="thermometer">
          <canvas id="termometar_cnv" width="160" height="600"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div id="inner2">
          <div id="gauge2_div"></div>
          <div class="below_gauge">Text #2</div>
        </div>
        <div id="thermometer2">
          <canvas id="termometar2_cnv" width="160" height="600"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="below">Description.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    padding: 5px;
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
#inner2 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
#gauge_div {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: green;
}
#gauge2_div {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: green;
}
#heading {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
}
#below {
    margin: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
}
.graph {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    border: thin solid #00F;
}
#container_main {
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}
#thermometer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0;
    background-color: gray;
}
#thermometer2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 0;
    background-color: gray;
}
.below_gauge {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
}
.below_gauge2 {
    width: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: blue;
}
```

When `<div class="below_gauge2">` is removed from the HTML the layout is exactly how I would like it to be. However, after adding that DIV, the green div moves up so it is not anymore vertically aligned with the second green div at the right.

What can be done so `<div class="below_gauge2">` would be displayed below the left green DIV, but in a such way the green DIV would stay where it was before adding the `<div class="below_gauge2">`?

Comment: Create a snippet instead of just posting your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zvxhxz5w/)

```
#inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;

    //added
    position: relative;
}

.below_gauge2 {
    width: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: blue;

    //added
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do, thank you very much! Now if I could only understand why that works :-/ Can you please explain why `#inner` must have the position property set to relative and how is the origin of `.below gauge2` calculated when positioned absolute? BTW, I did not have to put the last line since there already was `margin: 0 auto;` in the code before.

Comment: I added `position:relative;` to `#inner` so that `.below_gauge2` with `position:absolute;` would be relative to it and not with the `#container`. absolute position - The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.

Comment: I now understand the reason why you had to add `position: relative;` to `#inner` but still don't understand why `position: absolute;` doesn't move the div to the upper-left corner of `#inner` and how `left: 0; right: 0;` results with horizontal centering inside `#inner`. And why would `#inner` without `position: relative` be relative to `#container` and not to the document body?

Comment: I meant: 'And why would `.below_gauge2` without `position: relative` be relative to `#container` and not to document body?'

Comment: I was wrong, it was actually relative to the body. sorry, im not good at explaining things. check this https://jsfiddle.net/u3g3ekwf/1/ and try experimenting by removing some parts of the css like `left:0;` and `right:0;`

Comment: I can see the results (I already did experiments on my local files after you posted the answer). The problem is I don't understand *why* that works. I would like to understand how `absolute` property affects the calculation of the position of an element but w3c examples do not answer that question.

Comment: How about adding one more DIV below `.below_gauge2`, e.g. `.below_gauge3` - is that possible? I can't find a way to position it below `.below_gauge2` because `.below_gauge2` is removed from the flow by absolute positioning.

Comment: you can add a parent for `.below_gauge2` and `.below_gauge3` then position the parent `absolute` like `.below_gauge2` then change the position of `.below_gauge2` and `.below_gauge3`  to relative