# What is the right way to make this layout working?

Tags: css, alignment

What seemed to be a simple task turned out to be quite a problem. I am trying to find a way to both **preserve the vertical alignment of green DIVs** and to **prevent the absolute positioned DIV from overlapping the contents that follows**.

Since I had to use absolute positioning not to destroy the alignment, I am now looking for a solution to another problem that showed up as a consequence.

Here is the code:

```css
body {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #0000FF;
    padding: 5px;
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
}
#inner2 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
#gauge_div {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: green;
}
#gauge2_div {
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: green;
}
#heading {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
}
#below {
    margin: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    clear: both;
}
.graph {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    border: thin solid #00F;
}
#container_main {
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}
#thermometer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0;
    background-color: gray;
}
#thermometer2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 0;
    background-color: gray;
}
.below_gauge {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
}
.below_container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.below_gauge2 {
    width: 240px;
    color: blue;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
.below_gauge3 {
    width: 240px;
    color: blue;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    border: thin solid #F00;
}
```

```html
<div id="container_main">
  <div id="heading"><h1>The title</h1></div>
  <div class="graph">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="inner">
        <div id="gauge_div"></div>
        <div class="below_gauge">Text #1</div>
        <div class="below_container">
          <div class="below_gauge2">Here I would like to display some text but would not like the left square to be misaligned with the right one. That has been solved.</div>
          <div class="below_gauge3">I do not want the contents of this DIV to overlap the contents below. This DIV can contain any ammount of text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="thermometer">
        <canvas id="termometar_cnv" width="160" height="600"></canvas>
      </div>
      <div id="inner2">
        <div id="gauge2_div"></div>
        <div class="below_gauge">Text #2</div>
      </div>
      <div id="thermometer2">
        <canvas id="termometar2_cnv" width="160" height="600"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="below">Is there a way to make the DIV with the red border to push down this DIV so the DIV with the red border would not overlap what is below?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made this code based on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40901685/1324175) (that I accepted) to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40901618/1324175) when I had problems with how to allign two green DIVs. As can be seen the solution was to use absolute positioning but now that caused a problem because every absolute positioned element is according to CSS specification removed from the flow.

Comment: remove this part in css : `.below_container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}` or set `.below_container ` outside  `#container` and before  `#below` in the normal flux of your document :(  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgVbXp

Comment: As I said, I want to **preserve the vertical alignment of green DIVs**. I explained why I had to use `{ position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; }`. Your code destroys the vertical alignment of green DIV-s, the left green DIV has to be at the same vertical position as the one on the right.

Comment: But this is obviously not working , if position:absolute seemed a good idea, it is not. You have to rethink the structure or use javascript to find out if the footer stands where your absolute is standing ... sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try once Left-margin and right-margin.

Comment: this is a comment, be patient you will be soon able to comment :)

Comment: @GCyrillus it's not a comment. It's an answer.

Comment: ?? really, any explanation and reasons why he should try something about horizontal margins , You noticed it was about an absolute element and a footer in the flux not going down below (vertically) :) ....